# Javascript Change and Click events don't both fire

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, onchange

I have a textarea or input, and I change the text, and then click a link or button (without tabbing off the input), only the change event fires, not the click event. I want them both to fire:

```
Enter some text and then click the link. We want f1 and f2 to appear !
<br />
<input onchange="f1();" value="input text" />
<br />
<a href="" onclick="f2();">click me</a>


function f1() {
    alert("f1");
    return true;
}

function f2() {
    alert("f2");
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/vrcfherp/3/

I've tried it with jquery and normal js as above, and I've tried setTimeouts inside the functions, I've tried input and textarea, but whatever I do, only f1 fires.

**UPDATE 1**

So we've established that alerts kill any subsequent events - good. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/vrcfherp/7/)

Now the challenge is, how to stack up these events in an object so each event can fire an alert(or confirm, or ...) and NOT block any future events. I'm just trying different ideas. More to come...

**UPDATE 2**

I wrote some code to stack up the functions and then execute them at the end. Its not beautiful (and it should be wrapped in a class) but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/vrcfherp/9/

Comment: Your fiddle worked to me in Chrome.

Comment: first do this `f2(e){e.preventDefault() .... }` and secound please be more explained, you want after press click to execute f1 after f2 ?

Comment: start stopping `alert()` (which is modal and because then there is no click event fired, only [mousedown](http://jsfiddle.net/vrcfherp/5/)) for debugging purpose  http://jsfiddle.net/vrcfherp/4/

Comment: Works in Safari (9.0.2), too, only Firefox (43.0a2 here) behaves like described in the OP

Comment: It doesn't work for me in chrome, or FF or IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to the **blocking mode of alert**.

Browser will trigger the events one after the another. In this case the priority must be

1. onChange event of `<input>`
2. onClick event of `<a>`

but when it first executes onChange of input, it encouters `alert` which blocks rest of the things, hence the event onClick of anchor tag is not triggered.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vrcfherp/6/) if you change from alert to `console.log`

Comment: Thanks, in my app there's no alerts but I'm seeing the same behaviour the "blocking mode" comment is maybe the cause.  I'm trying a few things and will update.. thanks

Comment: Here's a fiddle to confirm it does work without alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/vrcfherp/7/

Comment: Good. Just adding to the point, when alert pops out, even we cannot scroll the browser window too. Anyway this question took much attention. :)

Comment: Its a real pain though because there is one circumstance where I need to popup a question to the user in the first event. I still want the second event click to fire, and it doesn't. I'll have to use timeouts I suppose

Comment: I'm not sure the timeout will help you, because event itself is not generated. May be designing again, like what to include in onClick and for onChange may solve the issue. It depends. You have updated your question, but you cannot stack/collect the events which not at all generated.

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` is modal and because `input` loses focus on other element mousedown, there is no click event fired.

So start using `console` for debugging purpose.